# как сделать так чтобы при запуске программы через модуль os не открывалась командная строка

Tags: python, ос

```
os.startfile('D://python/6.py')
```

у меня открывается программа которую нужно запустить и cmd можно ли как то отключить запуск cmd

Comment: использовать subprocess.Popen(['python', '-m 6.py', shell=False]

Comment: ошибка NameError: name 'subprocess' is not defined

Comment: @Dimonset ну наверное subprocess нужно импортировать, так же как вы os импортируете.

Comment: окей я импортировал но вопервых тут нету закрывающей скобки и нужно поставить два знака ровно

Comment: но даже после этого ошибка NameError: name 'shell' is not defined

Comment: @Dimonset, скобки в комменте Александра немного не правильно расставлены, должно быть так: `subprocess.Popen(['python', '-m 6.py'], shell=False)`

Comment: C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe: Error while finding module specification for ' 6.py' (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named ' 6'). Try using ' 6' instead of ' 6.py' as the module name.

Comment: у меня файл python хранится на диске Д тут не указан диск

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Похоже эта команда использует `cmd` команду `"start"` для запуска файла, поэтому отключить ее невозможно.
Добавлю, в `Python 3.10` добавлен аргумент `show_cmd`, так что теперь можно управлять опцией видимости программы `cmd`.
Из документации:

> Changed in version 3.10: Added the arguments, cwd and show_cmd
> arguments, and the os.startfile/2 audit event.

Полностью команда:

```py
os.startfile(path[, operation][, arguments][, cwd][, show_cmd])
```

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).